# How to change the window status with mouseover and mouseout?

Tags: javascript, java, html, mouse

I want to change the text of the status window when the mouse is over a link. My link's name is: Hipervinculo. 
Then, when the mouse is out of the link it should appear a different text.
This is my html until now, but it doesn't work.
Can someone explain me how to do it?
Thank you so much!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Práctica 4</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function info(txt){
        window.status="txt";
        }

        function info2(txt){
        window.status= "txt"
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>  

    <a href="Gato.html" ONMOUSEOVER="info('Por encima del hipervinculo...');return true;" ONMOUSEOUT="info2('Fuera del hipervínculo…');return true;" id="Enlace">Hipervínculo</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Whilst we understand that this may be a go to place, it might be worth having a read through this link: https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/how-to-ask-for-programming-help/amp/ and it will help you understand how to ask a question in a better manner. This question has probably been answered on the site, too, so you might want to have a bit of a dig around to find it! Good luck with your project! Stay safe, too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.status has been disabled in most (if not all) browsers for security reasons (it was possible to fake a different location for links that way).